# Why does this loop in C not work?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a loop so that a user can enter a number, and after each number they are prompted if they want to enter another number or not. If they choose anything but `n` or `N`, then count is increased, so the loop keeps going, but instead it doesn't!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    int nums[10], i, tot = 0;
    int answer;
    double avg;

    int count = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
        printf("Enter another number? ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        tot += nums[i];
        if (answer != 78 && answer != 110) {
            count++;
        }
        else { count = count - 1; }
        printf("[c:%d][i:%d]", count, i);
    }

}
```

The output I get:

```
Enter number 1: 2
Enter another number? y
[c:2][i:0]Enter number 2: 3
Enter another number? y
[c:3][i:1]Enter number 3: 4
Enter another number? n
[c:4][i:2]Enter number 4: 1
Enter another number? n
[c:5][i:3]Enter number 5: 2
Enter another number? n
[c:6][i:4]Enter number 6: 2
Enter another number? n
[c:7][i:5]Enter number 7: ^C
```

the count variable does not decrement when I enter `n` or `N`, why not? It's supposed to decrement to exit out of the loop, and using `break;` doesn't work either!

Comment: In your [c:][i:] debugging, you should add [answer:].  If you look at the loop, the only thing that would make sense is that answer is not what you think it is.  You should also check the return value of scanf.

Comment: Print out `answer` to check what you actually get.

Comment: Use a do while loop, with a char 'answer' variable to detect if the loop should end or not

Comment: Removing the space before `%c` will not allow me to enter input since it takes in `\n`.

Comment: Just for the record, it works on my (little-endian) box, so it's the endianness indeed (almost certainly).

Comment: Nah, it was just that I should have defined `int answer` as `char answer` lol.

Comment: It was the endianness causing that.  The char was being stored on the wrong part of the int.  But yes, making it a char does fix that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably want to make `answer` of type `char` instead  of int.

Comment: Wow, I always fall into dumb traps like this. Thank you!